# does “Sign in with google” mean "sign in with google play"?

Tags: google-oauth

If a user uses “Sign in with apple” (Oauth 2.0), he or she can be recognized as the user (with username and password) in the apple app store. My question is if a user uses “Sign in with google” (Oauth 2.0), can one be recognized as the user in the google play? In other words, is google account the same as google play account? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, it is. Isn't this something you could have figured out yourself?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am new to this area. It seems obvious to you. but it does not work for me that way.